# Flume and HDFS: Create one file per host and application

Tags: hadoop, logging, log4j, flume, flume-ng

I have several Java applications using Log4J that may or not be on the same host.

I've successfuly configured Flume and Log4J to persist a single file per day, but how can I make flume create separate directories based on host and application name?

This is my Flume Log4J Appender:

```
<Flume name="flumeLogger" compress="false" batchSize="1" type="persistent" dataDir="logs/flume">
    <Agent host="myhost" port="41414"/>
    <PatternLayout pattern="@@@@ %d{ISO8601} %p ${env:COMPUTERNAME} my-app %c %m @@@@"/>
</Flume>
```

And this is my Flume Configuration:

```
agent1.sinks.hdfs-sink1.type = hdfs
agent1.sinks.hdfs-sink1.hdfs.path = hdfs://localhost:9000/logs/%{host}
agent1.sinks.hdfs-sink1.hdfs.filePrefix = %y-%m-%d
agent1.sinks.hdfs-sink1.hdfs.round = true
agent1.sinks.hdfs-sink1.hdfs.roundValue = 1
rgent1.sinks.hdfs-sink1.hdfs.roundUnit = day
agent1.sinks.hdfs-sink1.hdfs.rollInterval = 0
agent1.sinks.hdfs-sink1.hdfs.rollFile = 0
agent1.sinks.hdfs-sink1.hdfs.rollSize = 0
agent1.sinks.hdfs-sink1.hdfs.rollCount = 0
agent1.sinks.hdfs-sink1.hdfs.writeFormat = Text
agent1.sinks.hdfs-sink1.hdfs.fileType = DataStream
agent1.sinks.hdfs-sink1.hdfs.batchSize = 1
agent1.sinks.hdfs-sink1.hdfs.useLocalTimeStamp = true

agent1.channels = ch1
agent1.sources = avro-source1
agent1.sinks = hdfs-sink1

agent1.sinks.hdfs-sink1.channel = ch1
agent1.sources.avro-source1.channels = ch1
```

From the [documentation](https://flume.apache.org/FlumeUserGuide.html#hdfs-sink):

> **%{host}**: Substitute value of event header named “host”. Arbitrary header names are supported.

However all my logs are being written in `/logs` instead of `/logs/myhost` as specified on the `hdfs.path` property.

Additionally, how can I define `arbitrary header names` in the Log4J Appender?